# How to call CSS class on a CakePHP Html->link?

Tags: cakephp

I am a complete noob to programming and CakePHP all together, so please be patient. How am I supposed to call the CSS on this Html->link:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Blogs', true), array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index') ); ?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "call the css", I think you want to add a class to this link? IF that's the case you can just add another array as an argument and it will turn key =? value into HTML attributes. EG:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Blogs', true), array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'my-class'));
```

This is all explained in the [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link).

Answer (score 3):

Another Solution will be the inline style :

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Blogs', true), array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), array('style' => 'color:red;font-size:20px;'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this CakePHP 3 in

```
<?php 
echo  $this->Html->link(__('Blogs'), ['controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'], ['class' => 'mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-warning']);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this works:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Add Task', array('action'=>'add'), array('class' => 'tac')); ?>
```

Comment: You should make sure that your answer is worked and you already try it.