# CSS classes in HTML links CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem adding CSS classes to my HTML links in CakePHP: I tried the solution as posted in: [How to call CSS class on a CakePHP Html->link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149468/how-to-call-css-class-on-a-cakephp-html-link)

If I put the links within the oldschool HTML div class 'my-class' it works.

If I use the code from the example it does not work:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Blogs', true), array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'my-class'));
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you including the Html-Helper? Are there any errors? Have you set debug to 2 in core.php?
What do you mean by "it does not work"? Only the class or the whole link?

Comment: works perfectly for me, i've copied your exact code and it outputs `<a class="my-class" href="/posts">Blogs</a>` you're gonna have to give us more info about your problem

Comment: Sorry, I cant include a code blok here at stackoverflow....very annoying to include html as your tab key is broken. Anyway, thanks for your help. I checked the output, exactly as it should be, the class is correctly mentioned. Also, the HTML helper is active as I can use other of its functions....only this link.. The link works, only the css style is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading your comments, I understand that the link in outputted correctly, the same for the class. Only that the styles associated with that class are not rendered. Am I right?

If so, have you included the CSS file? You should `$this->Html->css('style_name');`, where `style_name` is a CSS file located in `app/webroot/css/`.

Comment: The problem is not resolved. Sometimes it worked, then after an hour the css was gone. I have stopped using Elements started to implement the MenuBuilder helper. Thanks for all your help