# Cakephp how to remove underline on links

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, cakephp

New to cakephp came across a scenario where I have to make a text and an image a link.
Fortunately it was successful, however I noticed that there is an underline on my link and I have to remove it, as you can see on the picture below + the code on how I made it like that:
[image]

Cakephp Code:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
     $this->Html->image('img/f.png', array('height' => '40', 'width' => '40'))
     . '' . ('forensics express&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'), 
     'http://example.com', array('escape' => false));
```

normally this would be easy just by adding:

```
style="text-decoration:none"
```

in the css, however since I'm new to cake I am not aware of the syntax on how I can put an id or class that I can use for css, or in what I prefer, directly adding the ***style="text-decoration:none"*** in the array.I tried this one but it didn't work.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
     $this->Html->image('img/f.png', array('height' => '40', 'width' => '40'))
     . '' . ('forensics express&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'), 
     'http://example.com', array('escape' => false,'style'=>'text-decoration:none'));
```

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help

```
echo $this->Html->link(
$this->Html->image('img/f.png', array('height' => '40', 'width' => '40'))
 . '' . ('forensics express&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'), 
 'http://example.com', array('escape' => false,'class'=>'no-decoration'));
```

In the stylesheet, you can create this class

```
.no-decoration{
  text-decoratino:none;
}
```

You can use this as reference link : [How to call CSS class on a CakePHP Html->link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149468/how-to-call-css-class-on-a-cakephp-html-link)

Answer (score 2):

Just set it in your css *(stylesheet)* like this, instead of inline code.

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
```