# How to design the link in cakephp3 while using reverse routing

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to design the link in cakephp3 while using reverse routing? I have an anchor tag and that has a class but in reverse routing it already has the anchor and it is in array, so how can I design the link like background and add class?

Note: I want to design the anchor tag which name is `cancel` in my program

```
<div class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect w-md">
    <?=
    $this->Html->link(
            'Cancel', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'dashboard')
    );
    ?>
</div>
```

I have tried to add another array but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you want the HTML output of this to be?

Comment: How to add designs to it like we design a anchor tag with style.

Comment: You just want to add a `class` attribute to the link? That wasn't clear from the original question; it has nothing to do with routing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call CSS class on a CakePHP Html->link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149468/how-to-call-css-class-on-a-cakephp-html-link)

Comment: Here i am using reverse routing, and the way i added a class to the div, some styles are working and some not. And the "$this->Html->link()" creates a anchor tag so where should i add some style so that the anchor button should be as my style.

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave? Answers there clearly show how to add a class to a link.

Comment: I used this,my code 
~~~ 
<?php $this->Html->link(__('Edits' , true), array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'edituserss'), array('class'=> 'btn btn-custom waves-light waves-effect w-md')); ?>
~~~
 but its not showing anything

Comment: You used this code exactly? There's no echo there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html->link('Edit', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'edituser'), 
                           array('class' =>"btn btn-custom waves-light waves-effect w-md")
                            );?>